# render* functions don't dispay in modalDialog inside shiny module

Tags: r, shiny

I have been using `showModal(modalDialog(...))` to display graphs as pop-ups in my shiny apps, but these plots don't render when I put them inside a shiny module.

Short repro below: the non-module triggers modal displays the graph, the module triggered modal has it blank. Anyone have any ideas? The modal itself is displayed correctly, as does non-reactive contents of the modal (e.g. `ModalDialog('some text')`)

```
library(shiny)

# Module UI
myModuleUI = function(id){
  ns = NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    actionButton(ns('button'), 'Module')
  )
}

# Module server
myModule = function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        # This renderPlot does not display
        renderPlot(ggplot2::qplot(mtcars$mpg))
      )
    )
  })
}

# App UI
ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    actionButton('nonModule', 'Non-module'),
    myModuleUI('module')
  )
)

# App server
server = function(input, output) {
  modalFunc = function() {
    return(modalDialog(renderText("Non-Module"),
                       renderPlot(ggplot2::qplot(mtcars$mpg))))
  }

  observeEvent(input$nonModule, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        # This renderPlot does display
        renderPlot(ggplot2::qplot(mtcars$mpg))
      )
    )
  })

  callModule(myModule, 'module')
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

SessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.13.3

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     digest_0.6.12    mime_0.5         grid_3.3.2       R6_2.2.2         plyr_1.8.4       xtable_1.8-2    
 [8] jsonlite_1.5     gtable_0.2.0     scales_0.4.1     ggplot2_2.2.1    rlang_0.1.2      lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3    
[15] tools_3.3.2      munsell_0.4.3    httpuv_1.3.5     yaml_2.1.14      colorspace_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6  tibble_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Edit

After posting this answer, I reported this behavior to shinys issue tracking system on GitHub and [a fix](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/2010) was provided a few days later. Therefore, you can update shiny to the newest version from GitHub to get this to work. Alternatively, use the solution I provided below.

### Original answer

If you assign a seperate `output` slot for the plot, both modals work properly.

```
myModule = function(input, output, session){
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot2::qplot(mtcars$mpg)
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        # This plot does display
        plotOutput(session$ns("plot"))
      )
    )
  })
}
```

I am not sure what causes this. Have you observed the same behavior with other render functions?

#### My guess on why this happens

AFAIK using `renderXXX` in ui definitions (such as the `...` argument in `modalDialog`) is only supposed to work in `RMarkdown` documents. For example, the documentation of the `outputArgs` argument in `?renderPlot` reads

> **outputArgs** A list of arguments to be passed through to the implicit call to plotOutput when renderPlot is used in an interactive R Markdown document.

Similar statements can be found in `?markRenderFunction`. So the fact that

```
showModal(modalDialog(renderPlot(...)))
```

even works outside `RMarkdown` documets is an undocumented and therefore unreliable feature.

Comment: `renderText` also had the same issue. I'm not sure why using these functions work in ui definitions anyway, your suggested pattern works for me.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I just did more testng and the same bug happens in Markdown documents as well. Maybe these implicit calls have just never been adapted to modules properly.